# How to check if pair of values in array of pairs of values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose we have an object whose has the dimensions `$height` and `$width`. Rather than do this:

```
if(
   ($height = 500 && $width = 400)
|| ($height = 200 && $width = 380)
|| ($height = 850 && $width = 780)
|| ...
) { ...
```

...is there a "shorthand" (i.e. easy for humans to read and maintain) way in PHP to check if the array `[$height, $width]` is in the following array of arrays?

```
[ [500,400], [200,380] [850, 780] ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) can work with arrays:

```
<?php
$dimensions = [[500, 400], [200, 380], [850, 780]];

$needle1 = [500, 400];
$needle2 = [500, 440];

echo "needle1 in array: ".in_array($needle1, $dimensions)."\n";
echo "needle2 in array: ".in_array($needle2, $dimensions)."\n";
```

([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7dcb95f3d6bf3afb5c1bf86ca133f5e89ab513ff))

Comment: Thanks Marvin, my array game isn't strong - I generally cast all my arrays to bespoke `Traversable` objects, then just work quite basically with them. I'll accept this answer when the timer runs down in a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
 $widths=[500,200,850];
 $heights=[400,380,780];
 if(in_array($width,$widths) && in_array($height,$heights)){
 ...
 }
```

Comment: This will fail when 500x400 is acceptable, but 500x380 isn't.  Thanks for your answer though, very close, the one given by @Marvin is the correct one I believe.